# Beamer: Short section titles in Headline

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I have a beamer template for a presentation. In this template, the headline shows the section name and the subsection to which the current slide belongs to.
However, even if I have defined a short title as in

```
\section[Short title]{The very long title that surely is way too long}
```

the headline always shows the long title.

Here is the code from the style file which shows the section name

```
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\beamer@headline@lmargin}{-0.55\beamer@headline@height},left,center]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[dp=0.5ex]{section in head/foot}
            \shadowtextline{\insertsection}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
```

So my question: Is there any other command for \insertsection in order to show the short title? (I assume no, as googleing it I didn't really find anything). Additionally, does it matter if not all sections have short titles?

Comment: from section 10.2 in beameruserguide.pdf, looks like `\inserttocsection` is what you are looking for.

Comment: This gives me a 'Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \inserttocsection'

Comment: Use braces `{}` for the mandatory (second) argument in the `\section` command. If this does not help, could you please provide a  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Sorry, I actually did use curly braces in my code. An MWE would really be just something like \section[1]{Sec1} and then some slides

Comment: A complete minimal example starts with `\documentclass` and finishes with `\end{document}`. And it contains a minimum number of packages, command/environment definitions, pages/frames to show your problem. Please, read the link provided by crixstox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your outer theme should use `\insertsectionhead` instead of `\insertsection`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\section[Short section 1 title]{Long section 1 title}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{F1}
  Long title: \insertsection

  Short title: \insertsectionhead
\end{frame}

\section[Short section 2 title]{Long section 2 title}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{F2}
  Long title: \insertsection

  Short title: \insertsectionhead
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]